# DataContract dll used in WCF Service project and a client Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service project in which i included datacontract dll.
Then i have a client .NET application build in WPF which uses the same data contract dll.
The problem is when i pass the entity filled from client application to webservice application and check the same entity over there, some of the data is available as null there, despite the fact that i passed it from the client applicaion.

Is there any thing missing on my part?

Comment: @msm8bball: it is very well possible to share DataContract classes between the server and the client as the OP describes. When adding a service reference, you can decide to reuse types from referenced assemblies (button "Advanced" in the Add Service Reference dialog).

Comment: @user1300974: Can you post one of the DataContracts and show which properties are not filled? Can it be that the properties in question are marked with `[IgnoreDataMember]` attributes?

Comment: Check the datacontracts and see if all your properties are decorated with the [DataMember] attribute.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please?

Comment: Show us the data contract...it should not be behaving like this...